# Magic code for level binary tree traversal - what is going on?

Tags: algorithm, tree, functional-programming, ocaml

We have a definition of binary tree:

```
type 'a tree =
  | Node of 'a tree * 'a * 'a tree
  | Null;;
```

And also a helpful function for traversing the tree"

```
let rec fold_tree f a t =
  match t with
  | Null -> a
  | Node (l, x, r) -> f x (fold_tree f a l) (fold_tree f a r);;
```

And here is a "magic" function which, when given a binary tree, returns a list in which we have lists of elements on particular levels, for example, when given a tree:

[image: tree]
<sub>(source: [ernet.in](http://lcm.csa.iisc.ernet.in/dsa/img151.gif))</sub>

the function returns [[1];[2;3];[4;5;6;7];[8;9]].

```
let levels tree =
  let aux x fl fp = 
    fun l ->
    match l with
    | [] -> [x] :: (fl (fp []))
    | h :: t -> (x :: h) :: (fl (fp t))
  in fold_tree aux (fun x -> x) tree [];;
```

And apparently it works, but I can't wrap my mind around it. Could anyone explain in simple terms what is going on? Why does this function work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you combine two layer lists of two subtrees and get a layer list of a bugger tree? Suppose you have this tree

```
   a
  / \
 x   y
```

where `x` and `y` are arbitrary trees, and they have their layer lists as `[[x00,x01,...],[x10,x11,...],...]` and `[[y00,y01,...],[y10,y11,...],...]` respectively.

The layer list of the new tree will be `[[a],[x00,x01,...]++[y00,y01,...],[x10,x11,...]++[y10,y11,...],...]`. How does this function build it?

Let's look at this definition

```
let rec fold_tree f a t = ...
```

and see what kind of arguments we are passing to `fold_tree` in our definition of `levels`.

```
... in fold_tree aux (fun x -> x) tree []
```

So the first argument, `aux`, is some kind of long and complicated function. We will return to it later.

The second argument is also a function — the identity function. This means that `fold_tree` will also return a function, because `fold_tree` always returns the same type of value as its second argument. We will argue that the function `fold_tree` applied to this set of arguments takes a list of layers, and adds layers of a given tree to it.

The third argument is our tree.

Wait, what's the fourth argument? `fold_tree` is only supposed to get tree? Yes, but since it returns a function (see above), that function gets applied to that fourth argument, the empty list.

So let's return to `aux`. This `aux` function accepts three arguments. One is the element of the tree, and two others are the results of the folds of the subtrees, that is, whatever `fold_tree` returns. In our case, these two things are functions again.

So `aux` gets a tree element and two functions, and returns yet another function. Which function is that? It takes a list of layers, and adds layers of a given tree to it. How it does that? It prepends the root of the tree to the first element (which is the top layer) of the list, and then adds the layers of the right subtree to the tail of the list (which is all the layers below the top) by calling the *right function* on it, and then adds the layers of the left subtree to the result by calling the *left function* on it. Or, if the incoming list is empty, it just the layers list afresh by applying the above step to the empty list.

Comment: I understand everything but last paragraph. I mean, how does folding work? What exactly are fl and fp, when did they become lists?

Comment: fl and fp are functions, not lists. They are results of `fold_tree` applied to the subtrees. These functions are applied to a list of levels and the result is a new list of levels.

Comment: Ok, maybe I just asked the wrong question. I meant, in `aux` we have two cases for matching -  empty list, and a list with some elements. When is something else than an empty list given to this function? Also, how can we imagine `fl` and `fp` on corresponding "levels of folding"? For example, in the tree I posted I'm on the node with 4. How does `fl` look for the node with 8 and how does `fp` look for the node with 9? And when we're at node 1, how passing information between `fl` and `fp` works, I mean, how do they know that they must "merge" [4;5] [6;7] in one list, for example?

Comment: Let's do it in order. 1. A non-empty (singleton) list is generated right on the line where an empty list is matched. Then it is returned and given to the next function.

Comment: 2. In each node there is a function that transforms a list of levels to another list of levels. Let's say we are at level N. Our list starts at level N. The function appends *its* node to the level N, and then takes the *tail* of the list and passes it to the child nodes. The functions in the child nodes will see all the layers starting from N+1 which is what they need.